# building a 3 input logic gate combination bounded by a simple if else statement

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

For 3 variables `x`,`y`,`z` and output `w` I need help buiding a logic circuit that can implement [image]

i.e. the logic diagram for the truth table: [image]

Comment: This looks very much like a homework problem so we will expect you to show a significant amount of effort and ask specific questions. How much do you know about building logic circuits? Do you know what a Karnaugh map is?

Comment: it's not home work. zero knowledge on building logic circuit

Comment: Hint: this function is called a *multiplexer*.

Answer (score -1):

1)Simplify your truth table by making Z "don't care" when X=1, Y "don't care" when x=0

2)Try breaking the problem down into sub circuits:
A = X AND Y
B = Z AND (NOT X)
W = A OR B